# Modify VB script

Tags: vba

I am completely not familiar with VB but I have to modify one line. That's why I'm asking community for help.
I have this line:

```
netfile1 = "\\server1\folder1\folder2\2015-01\" & FileNameLessDir(ABCFileName)
```

It works now but I have to replace `2015-01` with something that would take care of date like `YYYY-dd` or etc.
Could someone please help me how to modify the line and replace literal with placeholder that would work not dependent on 'hard-coded' line.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251755(v=office.15).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really clear what you want to do, but on a very general way:

```
dd = Day(Now()) 'current day
'uncomment below line if you want "1" to be "01"
'If dd < 10 Then dd = "0" & dd
mm = Month(Now()) 'current month
'uncomment below line if you want January to be "01"
'If mm < 10 Then mm = "0" & mm
yy = Year(Now()) 'current year
```

And this is how you concatenate strings:

```
netfile1 = "\\server1\folder1\folder2\" & yy & "-" & mm &"\" & FileNameLessDir(ABCFileName)
```

The string above will be:

```
netfile1 = "\\server1\folder1\folder2\2015-01\FileNameLessDir(ABCFileName)
```

if you run the code on January 2015,

```
netfile1 = "\\server1\folder1\folder2\2015-02\FileNameLessDir(ABCFileName)
```

if you run the code on February 2015 etc.

Play around with it to get your desired output (concatenate days, months, previous days, previous months etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Format the 'Date' output:

```
netfile1 = "\\server1\folder1\folder2\" & Format(Date, "YYYY-MM") & "\" & FileNameLessDir(ABCFileName)
```